# Trouble adding `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in a SwiftUI app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My problem is that I don't understand how to resolve this warning: `⚠️ Warning: Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'delegate' is 'weak'`

[Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) state:

> You must assign your delegate object to the UNUserNotificationCenter object before your app finishes launching.

In a SwiftUI app that doesn't use AppDelegate, that means I should assign it in `App.init()`.

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class UNCDelegate: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // this is where I think I can respond to the user's tapping on a notification
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataController: DataController()
    
    init() {
        let UNC = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        UNC.delegate = UNCDelegate() // ⚠️ Warning: Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'delegate' is 'weak'
        // Here I would want to share the UNC across the app by putting it into the SwiftUI environment somehow, so I can schedule notifications whenever I want and still use the handlers in the delegate
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised if my approach is all wrong. There aren't many examples online that match my use case. My ultimate goal is to open a specific route when user taps on a notification. But with the intention of keeping the question specific, I want to understand how to assign the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the `delegate` property is `weak`, so after that line, nothing will be holding a strong reference to the newly created `UNCDelegate` object, and it will be deallocated.

So just put it in `MyApp` instead, so that it doesn't get deallocated.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var uncDelegate = UNCDelegate()
    
    init() {
        let UNC = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        UNC.delegate = uncDelegate
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I see! Another question: is this a typical way to assign a UNC delegate? Is the next step to somehow put `UNC` into the environment so I can share it throughout the app for when I need to schedule a notif? Or is this not really the way it's done?

Comment: @nth-chile Actually, I forgot to make it a `StateObject`, which would keep it alive. You don't need the environment - you can just pass it into your views through your views' initialisers. See a more complete tutorial [here](https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/how-to-handle-push-notifications-in-swiftuis-new-app-lifecycle-7532c21d32d7).

Comment: I forked the gist in that article and stripped out some unnecessary code. I'm still not sure how the delegate gets used, since the notification gets scheduled on a seemingly separate instance of UNC. Gist here: https://gist.github.com/nth-chile/9b9536fc27ffa2e53d0a1e4ba1158aaf

Comment: @nth-chile Just to be clear, do you not understand how the code works and want an explanation for how it works, or does the code not work and want a fix? If it is the former, there is no "separate instance" of `UNUserNotificationCenter` here. You are always using the `current` one, and that does not change, so I'm not sure what you are talking about. Are you just not familiar with the delegate pattern in general? Either way, I would suggest that you ask a new question since this has become a very different question from the original post.

Comment: I just got it working. I didn't realize `.current()` was a singleton